# How can I pass comma separated value in cursor's select statement where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have following Block which has a cursor and a select query. I want to pass the output of select, which is comma separated into
the cursor's select statement, into the where clause. 
I know below code will throw an error because of SQL query in Declare section but how I achieve this using array or collection.

here, id column is number

code snippet:

```
declare
test varchar2(30);
SELECT LISTAGG(value, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value2) into test from table3 where value2=12;
cursor c1 (select * from table where id in (test))
begin
for i in c1 loop
null;
end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why would you ever do this?

You can simple write you select as:

`Select * from table where id in (select value from table3 where value2=12)`

Edit:

Also you need to open your cursor c1, for it to work AFAIK.

Comment: An implicit cursor loop doesn't require an `OPEN` statement

Comment: "Why would you ever do this?" When you want to process the list of values using PL/SQL between the reading the filter values from the first table and using them to filter the output of the second table.

Comment: @MT0 But there is no reason to make this into 2 SQL statements, and saving the reply in a scoped variable. When you can build up the the whole cursor and only do 1 IO.

Comment: In this simple case when you are not doing anything between getting the values and filtering on them then there is no reason but if you introduce an intermediate step where the list of filter values are processed before the final query then there is a reason to use 2 SQL statements. Which is exactly the point I made in my previous comment.

Comment: Okay, but let's not make it a habbit, and extrapolate more complexity than the OP is asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a collection and the `MEMBER OF` operator:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE IntegerList  AS TABLE OF NUMBER(8,0);
/

CREATE TABLE table1 ( value, value2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( id, value ) AS
SELECT 1, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 22 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 33 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 77 FROM DUAL;
```

**PL/SQL**:

```
DECLARE
  test IntegerList;
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  SELECT value
  BULK COLLECT INTO test
  FROM   table1;

  FOR r IN ( SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id MEMBER OF test ) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r.id || ', ' || r.value );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
1, 11
3, 33
7, 77
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1158097d8be9aa6d323dc7bd582fe877)*